# Debugging with IIS Express starts wrong application on Windows 1809

Tags: iis-express

I'm having a weird situation. Our VS solution has been setup for a while, we run an API project and a couple of Web projects. When we start debugging, IIS Express Usually fires the API and the selected web projects with no trouble, even handling custom domains from the applicationhost.config file. I always run VS as Administrator.

Since updating to the 1809 version of windows, IIS Express has been running strangely. I'm still running as Administrator. Instead of the API project starting, one of the web projects start. I can recreate this by right-clicking on the API project, clicking Debug - New Instance (with nothing else running/debugging) and IIS Express starts up with one of the web projects instead of the API project.

Pulling a fresh copy of the code from source control, still have the problem. Other devs on our team are running 1809 and this isn't happening.

I have no idea what is going on! What could be interfering? How can I figure out what IIS Express is doing?

***UPDATE***: I tried wiping out the entire repo folder, including `.vs` and the applicationhost.config file. Now when I try to start the API, all the web apps in the solution show up in IIS Express, but not the API.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow... and I thought I looked for this, a second entry for the API project was added to the ApplicationHost.config file. It was the same path, port, etc. Removing that allowed the API to run normally. Not sure why when it failed the other projects were started.